# Powershell to set multi-line legalnoticetext in registry - Windows 10

Tags: powershell, multiline, string-literals

Ok, been searching for the answer to this for hours and I can't believe I am not finding a clear cut solution. How do you enter multi-line text into "legalnoticetext" via script?

Key - Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System

I have this command for powershell

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" -Name "legalnoticetext" -Value "*** Authorized Access Only *** Second line of message..."
```

I have a multi paragraph message that needs to be added. I have tried multiple things, like \n, but am not stumbling on solution. I know it is easy to do this via the local GPO editor but I need to script it to run on a hundred remote machines.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- To embed a *newline* (line break) inside a `"..."` string literal, i.e. inside an [expandable (interpolating) string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings), use `` `n `` (or `` `r`n `` for Windows-format CRLF newlines).

  - See [about_Special_Characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Special_Characters).
  - Example:

    ```bash
    # Note the use of `n
    Set-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\...' `
      -Name legalnoticetext `
      -Value "*** Authorized Access Only ***`nSecond line of message..."
    ```
  - Note: Use of `"..."` implies that `$`-prefixed tokens in the string are subject to *expansion (string interpolation)*, unless the `$` characters are escaped with `` ` ``. If you prefer to use a [*verbatim* string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings) (`'...'`), you can use its *here-string* variant, as shown below.
- Alternatively, use a [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings), which allows you to use *literal* newlines in string literals.

  - Note: In here-strings, the newline *format* - LF-only (Unix-format) vs. CRLF (Windows-format) - is implied by the newline format of the *enclosing script file*.
  - Example:

    ```bash
    # Note the use of @'<newline>...<newline>'@
    Set-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\...' `
      -Name legalnoticetext `
      -Value @'
    *** Authorized Access Only ***
    Second line of message...
    '@
    ```

    - **Important**:

      - The *opening* delimiter, `@'` (or `@"` in *expandable* (interpolating) here-strings), must either be at the very end of the line or only be followed by whitespace.
      - The *closing* delimiter, `'@` (or `"@` in *expandable* (interpolating) here-strings) must be *at the very start of the line*.
      - *No* leading whitespace is stripped from the content of here-strings.